# 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known' error after deploying

Tags: c#, http, blazor-server-side

I am writing a blazor server side application (.NET6) for my homeautomation and let it run on IIS on a home server.

If I run the following code on my local machine in IIS Express everything works fine.

```
string _urlForecast = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=...";
Uri myUri = new Uri(_urlForecast, UriKind.Absolute);
HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(myUri);
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

If I deploy it to my local homeserver and run it I get the following error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (api.openweathermap.org:443)

My 'homeserver' is also running windows 10 and is in the same network as my dev PC.
It is in the same IP range and has the same DNS settings on the network adapter.
I also tried it with turned off firewall with the same result.
I am injecting the httpClient with DI but also tried without DI.
I tried to use http://api... and https://api... as my application is also available in the internal network via https. Unfortunately I have don't have any experience with Http requests.

Comment: This isn't a coding issue. You get a DNS error saying that `api.openweathermap.org` can't be found. Perhaps the DNS configuration of that machine has a problem? Or it has no access to external IPs, because eg it's blocked by a firewall? Have you tried running `nslookup api.openweathermap.org` on it?

Comment: The domain you used actually redirects to `openweathermap.org/api`. Try using `https://openweathermap.org/api` instead

Comment: I tried nslookup for both machines and I get the same result on both where it returns me 4 Addresses. But if I put one of the IPs in (and change it to http://IP... it works on my homeserver

Answer (score 0):

This is old post, but looking at the doc

https://openweathermap.org/appid

We can see that TLS is not supported.  (https://... will not work).

You also will need a key as part of your URL of course.

If the issue is TLS then the error you are getting makes sense, since that port (443) will be closed and not accepting requests.

Did you get the same error with a standard http request?